# IF ELSE Condition in mustache Grid

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, mustache

```
    <table style="font-size:12px;" class="table table-bordered accounts" id="example">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="text-align:center;">Action</th>
                <th>Plan Name</th>
                <th>Sales Force</th>
                <th>Natl. Acc</th>
                <th>Segment</th>
                <th>Example</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {{#{accounts}}
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align:center;"><a href="/FormularyData/tabs?segmentid={{PlanId}}"><i class="fa fa-cog fa-2x"></i></a></td>
                <td>{{PlanName}}</td>
                <td>{{PlanTypeName}}</td>
                <td>{{ParentPlanName}}</td>
                <td>{{SegmentName}}</td>
                <td>
                if ({{SegmentName}}=="S")
                    {
                         something
                     }
                else
                     {
                         something
                      }
               </td>

            </tr>
            {{/accounts}}
        </tbody>
    </table>



</script>
```

Load System:

```
 var templateWithData= Mustache.to_html($('#Tmp-Plans').html(),{accounts: data});
$("#con-accounts").empty().html(templateWithData);
```

Html Code:

```
<div id="con-accounts">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your load system you might wanna add something like

```
data.segmentNameCheck = function () {
    return data.SegmentName == 'S' 
}

var templateWithData= Mustache.to_html($('#Tmp-Plans').html(),{accounts: data});
```

in template do

```
{{#segmentNameCheck}} Something {{/segmentNameCheck}}
{{^segmentNameCheck}} Something Else {{/segmentNameCheck}}
```

Comment: sorry !! S means example not this it may anythings.

Comment: the point is, you can have a getter function in "data", check whatever you wanted to check as your "if" condition and in mustache template return that getter function.